# "Unexpected character" error when opening html file in Chrome from Sublime

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Very new to the programming world. All I want to do is open my html file from Sublime into google chrome. When I've researched an answer it tells me to do this:

```
{
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ]
    "selectedBrowser":
    [
        "chrome"
    ]
}
```

When I do that I get this message:
Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected character, expected a comma or closing bracket in Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings:6:2

Comment: Not a Sublime user, but I'm guessing there should be a comma in there between the closing bracket after "Vintage" and before the open quote on "selectedBrowser".

Answer (score 0):

Save the file as file-type .html somewhere, and then right-click -> Open with -> Google Chrome